# How to get package into house discreetly?

Tags: home, security

I've recently wanted to order some things, presents and the like, but I have no way to keep the package out of other's noses. In addition, the finding of the package by parents probably wouldn't end very well.

My situation:

- I can't drive to the store.
- Nearest Amazon Locker is about 30 miles away, well out of walking distance (By a lot)

The contents are roughly a foot in size, and should fit in one of those yellow shipping bags.

Comment: Tagging this was rather difficult, am I on the wrong site?

Comment: So you can't even receive an ordinary package of a book from Amazon without a bunch of questions?

Comment: @pboss3010 Story of my life. Also haven't ordered anything from Amazon before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have problems getting anything, so your choices are fairly limited. A) Have a trusted friend pick up or receive the package or B) intercept the delivery driver outside (also assuming you aren't being watched while outside). Once you secure the package, you should be able to stuff it into an empty backpack or underneath a jacket/coat (assuming by yellow shipping bag you mean an mailing envelope).

If your parents are the room search types, you're out of luck.

Comment: Room search types can normally be deceived by hiding things in their room :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Geez... that sounds scary.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix there is always the possibility you might find their hiding spot(s). That can certainly be scary

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Heh, not really sure I wanna find the hiding spot(s)

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you are ordering something from Amazon.

Option 1: Generally Amazon will have a 1 day or 2 day shipping options; now with this knowledge if you know your parents will be gone a certain day you could plan for it to be delivered on that day.

Option 2: You could talk to a next door neighbor and ask them if you could ship a package to their house, tell them it's a gift for one of your parents.

Option 2b: Ship it to a trusted friends house.

Option 2c: If you work, most workplaces will allow you to ship to that location. Just make sure to check with a manager first. I do this option all the time and the mailman started bringing all my packages to my work.

Comment: What happened to 2a!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a friend receive the item for you. You really have very limited options since you cant travel very far. Do you have a job? It is possible you could have it sent to your work location.

Comment: Well, the issue I have with someone else getting it is that by doing so I'm just making them figure out how to get the item, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your neighbors' address and get to it first. Stalk the door and get the package before the neighbors see it.

Answer (score 0):

change the name on the adress so they if your parents get it they think it was sent to the wrong person